# Using nuclear bombs to detect near earth orbit objects

Tags: experimental-physics, astronomy

This question is based on an article written some years ago by A. C. Clarke, in which he attempted to solve two problems with one solution.  His idea was to remove the Earth's stockpile of nuclear weapons by launching our current number of nuclear warheads
- 10,144 devices as at 2014 - into space. The next stage of his plan was to manoeuvre them onto an orbital position diametrically opposite Earth.

Then detonate the bombs and use the radiation emitted to act as a source for detecting near earth asteroids and comets by measuring the radiation reflected back.  This plan, if feasible, would increase our chances of early detection of potentially Earth directed NEO's and subsequent possible avoidance of another Tunguska like impact.

I assume this would require 3 (or more) separate bombs, using triangulation for location purposes.

Ignoring the political, environmental and logistical concerns involved in the transport of this nuclear material into space, my questions are:

Can the power output of a nuclear weapon be "tuned" to provide the maximum intensity at the most efficient frequency for reflection and subsequent detection by satellites?

Given the difference in the material composition of asteroids and comets, which frequency (or frequency range) would make this process most efficient?

Comment: There isn't a whole lot you can do to tune the spectrum, [see here](http://nuclearweaponarchive.org/Library/Teller.html) for the basic design of radiation implosion devices. You should  just assemble a few devices that are as powerful as you can make them, perhaps 100 Gigaton TNT. Then you get an output that is 20 times the power emitted by the Sun, albeit for a fraction of a second. That will generate enough of a signal that can be easily detected from Earth.

Comment: @Jimmy360   It comes with age :) I loved Science Fiction, especially the Arthur Clarke books, (but imo he was alway way too optimistic about human behavour).  Always loved this idea, just wondered was it doable, (physically only, practically ...naaah...not a chance)

Comment: @CountIblis  I assume it could be considered as a Gamma Ray Burst, just a **tiny** bit too close for comfort, although as you say, of short duration.  I am assuming, (as I have not yet looked as the link you sent me,) that most nuclear device radiation is in the x-ray/gamma end and that is what  military spy satellites are set up  to detect. I'll read the link,  thanks

Comment: Has anyone calculated what fraction of the fallout would stay close enough to earth orbit to end up in earth's atmosphere? I have a hunch it might be a bit more than one may hope for.

Comment: @pyramids: I don't think any would linger at the blast point, and if it did, it wouldn't matter because it's a stable Lagrangian point. The (moving) solid matter would get sent into "space" radially from the explosion at high velocity. There might be some gravitational lensing around the Sun that would focus a fraction at the Earth. One question might be at what radius from the Sun that material would pass and whether it would get vaporized along the way. The Earth-directed radiation would get absorbed by the Sun.

Comment: @pyramids hi good point. I wonder if locating the devices further away from earth than the distance quoted in the op would mitigate this fallout. Though I suppose the closer to the centre of the solar system  you used as the  detonation point, the more effective the detection rate. I don't have the  maths background to estimate the fallout, but even if it was relatively low, if it was in  earth orbit we would eventually encounter it.  Would the solar wind disperse it, or how does the fallout compare with current solar flux? I don't know these values.

Comment: @Dwin   I had thought about the L points, but for accurate position location of the NEOs,   I thought the devices would have to be dispersed, for more effective triangulation. How far apart in earth orbit I don't know, not 120 degrees anyway :) again I am out of my depth here on these aspects.

Comment: I was assuming (based on your description of Clarke's proposal) that they would be detonated only at L3. There's nothing that says that you cannot have multiple detonations. That way you could then "see" reflections at several times and thereby calculate trajectories.

Comment: Why would radiation from the explosions be better than our current methods of measurement (predominantly land-based optical surveys)? Also, an obvious problem with Clarke's idea (for the purpose of identitfying NEO's, not ridding ourselves of nuclear weapons) is that it's a "one-time ping", ideally we would have a system with multiple ping's. It seems like a cute idea but utter nonsense. I lost some respect for Clarke when I saw this interview https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKQQAv5svkk and he attributed black hole characteristics to fractals.

Comment: Mainly because we use light.. so low albedo = no reflection.  Handy to have another frequency. Yeah, I do totally agree that he did go overboard on fractals, imo, it was a new thing back then and he pushed it too far. I guess your point with multiple pings is it's easier to track the more data points you have. How about 5 or 6 smaller pings/bombs spaced over time?  As far as radiation goes, I don't know how it compares to other sources, so no opinion on that. Still,  to balance the books a bit, geostationary orbits? :) regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is a summary, based  on what I consider to be the most salient points made in the comments above. It is closely linked to the answer of my later question, [Deflection of Earth directed NEOs using nuclear powered laser beams](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/171932/can-a-nuclear-bomb-be-used-as-the-power-source-for-a-laser-beam)

Below is the answer I received in relation to my second question:

[Project Excalibur](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Excalibur)
 The idea of a nuclear pumped X-ray laser was one which was investigated in detail in the Reagan "Star Wars" program of the 1980s, backed by one Edward Teller. Tests were carried out by surrounding the nuke with bundles of rods to create a one-pass laser. Apparently it was nowhere near efficient enough to be used in a military context.

So further testing would be required to determine if we could actually **deflect** an NEO using a laser beam. However, as the energy level needed to merely produce a reflection detectable on Earth would be much less than the deflection energy, I would conclude that detection may well be a viable proposition.

This comment from Count Iblis, above,

*You should just assemble a few devices that are as powerful as you can make them, perhaps 100 Gigaton TNT. Then you get an output that is 20 times the power emitted by the Sun, albeit for a fraction of a second. That will generate enough of a signal that can be easily detected from Earth*

may support my argument that it may be possible to detect NEOs.

This comment from Dwin is also relevant in establishing the orbital parameters involved:

*There's nothing that says that you cannot have multiple detonations. That way you could then "see" reflections at several times and thereby calculate trajectories*