# Can a nuclear bomb be used as the power source for a laser beam

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics

My previous post "[Using nuclear bombs to detect near earth orbit objects](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/171725/using-nuclear-bombs-to-detect-near-earth-orbit-objects)" asked about using nuclear devices to detect Earth directed asteroids and low albedo comets.  Now I want to explore a method of deflecting them using lasers.

Assume we can, by (light, x or gamma rays), actually detect the incoming object on a timescale long enough to attempt to deflect it successfully.

Also assume that the NEO does not simply absorb the radation, as a comet might.

I don't need much (or anything really) in the answer by way of calculations, my question is simply:

Is it in principle possible to convert the energy of a nuclear blast, at any appreciable efficiency level, into the production of an intense laser beam?

This intense beam may then be directed at the NEO, possibly producing a deflection in it's path towards Earth.

I acknowledge that this process may be considered impossible, as placing delicate equipment near a nuclear blast is generally not recommended for the completion of any project.

But in defence of the merits of the question, two points:

As far as I remember, the base of the tower used in the Trinity device in New Mexico did not undergo as much damage as was originally expected.

The Project Orion spaceship design of the early 1960's proposed using very small nuclear devices. The calculations involved indicated that the vehicle would not be damaged by the estimated number ( in the order of hundreds) of nuclear blasts required to achieve orbit.

To sum up my question, can the radiation output of a nuclear device be used, even in principle, as the power source for a laser beam (the laser beam being tuned to whatever frequency is deemed most efficient for deflection purposes.)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_pumped_laser but I don't know any details

Comment: @SteveB Hi steve first thanks for the quick reply and second (and **no** conspiracy angle to this  :) I'd put good money on a gamble that a lot of classified reseach has been done on this. Just be good to see that research applied to a potentially lethal problem (no matter how remote the probability)..all the best

Comment: I'm fairly confident that a laser could not deflect an asteroid or other such object. And, while it is *theoretically* possible to power a laser with a nuclear bomb, I'm not sure why you'd want to. There are much safer and more effective ways of powering a laser. Anything powered by a nuke would have a high intensity and short duration effect. For deflecting a NEO, you essentially need to provide such a large acceleration in the short time that it would simply break apart. A nuclear reactor would be more effective in virtually every way.

Comment: @Jimnosperm  _Anything powered by a nuke would have a high intensity and short duration effect_  that's a 100 percent valid point and pretty much answers the question thanks

Comment: May I suggest an alternative, solar-powered chemical lasers? I think they have originally been conceived as a possible power link between space-based solar farms and a power receiver on earth, but who knows, maybe the idea works for some alternative purpose or other as well... I can't find a link right away, but [wikipedia's solar-pumped laser entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar-pumped_laser) may get you started anyways.

Comment: @pyramids   hi   as Jimnosperm says _I'm fairly confident that a laser could not deflect an asteroid or other such object_ and the more i think about it , that is really is the biggest unknown to me, would the "rock" really be affected by the beam, no matter how the laser was powered. I don't lose too much sleep over the prospect of a hit, it's remote enough I think, but in the last 100 years we have seen Shoemaker-Levy hit Jupiter, the Russian fireball recently, Tunguska....so fingers crossed :) regards

Comment: @irishphysics Yes, the laser would deflect the asteroid. At a minimum, the photons would be absorbed (or reflected) and hence transfer their momentum. That is energy-inefficient propulsion (the energy-impulse relationship indeed has the speed of light where non-relativistically you would indeed expect the speed of a moving massive particle), but it is not zero and very targetable. In reality, the effect would be greatly enhanced by evaporating material from the asteroid, creating a bit additional push (but still much more than the photon recoil, though). You just need power. Lots.

Comment: @pyramids from the photon absorption POV, that's ok. It's reflection from stray angles that makes me think, is the deflection controllable?  I'm sure you have seen meteorites at first hand and how uneven their surfaces are. Would the beam width be enough to average out reflections from all angles to provide a measure of control. Although, as long as it goes **anywhere** else but here, who cares? Good point about the evaporation effect, a small rocket motor just nudging it slowly away from impact. As you know, the main thing is to see the bloody thing early enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Project Excalibur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Excalibur)
The idea of a nuclear pumped X-ray laser was one which was investigated in detail in the Reagan "Star Wars" program of the 1980s, backed by one Edward Teller. Tests were carried out  by surrounding the nuke with bundles of rods to create a one-pass laser. Apparently it was nowhere near efficient enough to be used in a military context. [That latter fact was reported at the time but is not mentioned in the wiki article]

Comment: Additional information, mainly from memory, so this should not appear in the answer. IIRC the effectiveness of the tests fell short of expectations/hopes by around 6 orders of magnitude.

Comment: They were looking for TeraJoule output and got MegaJoule.

Comment: Hi, even without looking up wikipedia, I don't know why I immediately started thinking of Dr. Strangelove as soon as I saw your answer...I really don't........:)  i'm not sure what's scarier, impact with an asteroid or some of the "good" Doctor's ideas  thanks for your answer

Comment: @DirkBruere I seem to recall from the time that this project was the one where SDI bigwigs made a press statement to the effect of "we're halfway there" on learning that the power output was $10^6$ rather than $10^{12}$ joules. Well, 6 *is* half of twelve after all, what's a logarithm between friends?

Comment: Yes - I remember that quote as well about "being halfway there"